# drawing diagrams of roof of house

Tags: graphics

I am a furniture maker who wants to be able to generate a means to explain the geometry of a problem and how to solve it. Example: Roof rafters and their lengths dependent upon the angle of the roof. I would like to draw a picture of a house in its various details and show how to figure the lengths of various parts. I have no idea how to ask the question in Mathematica.

Comment: What is the functional relationship between e.g. the angle of the roof and the length of the rafters?

Comment: Basically all roof systems are the geometry of triangles and rectangles positioned so they correctly intersect each other. I can figure out the math that I want to know is how does one draw the figure that represents the roof beams.

Comment: Nice practical question! I would say it is better not to draw, but to select from a few predefined shapes and then do the necessary computations to determine the length of roof rafters.  Gable, cross-gabled, mansard, hip, gambrel, dormer. Do you need them all, or just one specific type?

Answer (score 2):

I think what MarcoB was trying to indicate is that many of us probably are not familiar with the requirements for rafters; I know I'm definitely not. This makes it a bit hard to program what the rafter should look like. It seems like there are several different styles of rafters, so I picked a style that seemed to match what I remember rafters looking like. If this isn't what you wanted, you might be able to improve the diagram yourself, or else you can edit the question to include more details about your requirements.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    FaceForm[None],
    EdgeForm[Black],
    ASATriangle[angle Degree, side, angle Degree],
    Rectangle[{-len + side/2, 0}, {len + side/2, (side/2 - len) Tan[angle Degree]}],
    Line[{
        {-len + side/2, (side/2 - len) Tan[angle Degree]}, 
        {side/2, 0}, {len + side/2, (side/2 - len) Tan[angle Degree]}
      }]
    },
    Frame -> True],
  {{angle, 30}, 0.1, 89.9},
  {{side, 1}, 1, 200},
  {{len, 0.25}, 0, side/2}
]
```

[image: Diagram of a rafter.]

Comment: Thank you I will work with this. I am just starting to learn so thanks.

Comment: I have rewritten this into a notebook and it tells me there is no code to run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DaleF.Victor Ummm, I'm not sure. I've never heard of such an error. Even if I run a completely empty notebook I don't get an error aside from a beep. Does it display an error message of some kind, either in the notebook or a message window? Also, what version are you running?

Comment: I found the introduction to Mathematica videos and learned much from watching them. Thanks for not calling me an idiot, I might have done this. It seems to me that there is a totally new set of customers and users if somehow there was a way to get people who are not in school and not familiar with Math to come here. I work with a number of really smart people how have dropped out of high school. They are smart and because they do woodworking and build things they have a knack for geometry even though they will deny this.

Comment: In this project, I am trying to show how roof structures work and the math that goes with them. I will figure it out, Hopefully, I will also take good enough notes so the uninformed can learn this. What would be really cool, perhaps this already exists, is for there to be an easy manner in which to draw things, like AutoCAD LT, but without the cost, that was a part of Mathematica so people without direct knowledge of Mathematica could just start to draw and get the math out of it. I would be interested in helping with this if there is an effort in this direction. .

Comment: I could see another use, which is in here somewhere, for the use of Boolean algebra for logic on an introductory level. Think of people who need to know about this information but are not in school or are near a place where it is taught. I work and do all the things other people do but I have an insatiable appetite for math for some reason, went to college a long time ago

Comment: @DaleF.Victor I've worked with millwrights that also thought they "weren't good at math", but were actually quite skilled with geometry and didn't realize how valuable that was. I tend to agree, I think that the visual nature of Mathematica lends itself well to a wide variety of fields. Certainly it would be possible to build something like what you envision for drawing and shapes in Mathematica, but it would be a substantial effort. I'm sure myself and others would be happy to answer smaller, self-contained questions, but I doubt anyone would have the time to take on the entire project.

Comment: I have been playing with Mathematica for some time but have not really had the time to get anywhere. What I want to do is easy and that is probably why I am having trouble. If I can get some help I would be interested in proceeding with these kinds of projects. I think that the visibility Mathematica offers would make this a hit.

Comment: @DaleF.Victor Feel free to post any specific questions you have. Even somewhat general questions have a decent chance of getting answered.